# Running 15.04: Sound only working in headphones

Tags: sound, 15.04, headphones, speakers

Dual-booted ubuntu and w7 on a ThinkPad T420. I was using headphones earlier today, but now the sound does not work from computer's speakers.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is for Ubuntu in a default configuration, so open your sound settings. If you're in Unity in Ubuntu, click the speaker in the upper right corner, and select "Sound Settings..."

You should end up on the Outputs tab of the sound settings. In the "Play sound through" list, select your "Speakers". If that is already selected, look to the top and right of that list and see if the volume sliders and other controls  make sense.

Comment: I have already done this, but I'll try it again